# Generalizing a notion of purely unrectifiable sets

Tags: geometric-measure-theory

The Besicovitch-Federer structure theorem enables us to make the following definition:

> Suppose $k < n$, $E \subset \mathbf{R}^n$, and $0 < \mathcal{H}^k(E) < \infty$. We say $E$ is **purely unrectifiable**, provided that  $\mathcal{H}^k(\pi_K(E))= 0$ for almost every $k$-plane $K$.

Many examples of such purely unrectifiable sets are known (see for example, Frank Morgan's book on geometric measure theory).

We can now try to make the following definition:

> Suppose $d \leq k < n$, $F \subset \mathbf{R}^n$, and $0 < \mathcal{H}^d(F) < \infty$. We say $F$ is **$(d, k)$-unrectifiable**, provided that  $\mathcal{H}^d(\pi_K(F))= 0$ for almost every $k$-plane $K$.

Thus, in my terminology $(k,k)$-unrectifiability is what is also called pure unrectifiability.

Is anything known about the case $d < k$? It doesn't seem obvious that such sets $F$ can't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually quite a lot is known about such sets. You can find many results in Chapter 9 of Mattila's *Geometry of Sets and Measures in Euclidean Spaces*. Here are some examples:

> **Theorem 1.** If $0<d\leq 1$, then there is a set $F\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $0<H^d(F)<\infty$, but projections on
>   every line have $H^d$ measure zero.

That implies that a set can be $(d,k)$-unrectifiable and still have positive $H^d$-measure. However, we also have

> **Theorem 2.** If $F\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is Borel and $d\leq k<n$ and $\dim F\leq k$, then $\dim \pi_K(F)=\dim F$ for allmost all $k$-planes
>   $K$.

Here $\dim$ stands for the Hausdorff dimension.

In particular, if in addition $0<H^d(F)<\infty$ (as in your assumption), then $\dim\pi_K(F)=d$ for alsmost all $k$-planes $K$. However, Theorem 1 shows in general you cannot expect $H^d(\pi_K(F))$ to be positive.

Comment: Thanks Piotr for the information and the reference! One question: in what sense is the dimension taken in Theorem 2?

Comment: @DrewBrady I added: dim is the Hausdorff dimension.